# Reshaping tensor in Numpy from 2D to 3D

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, reshape, tensor

I am using the EMNIST dataset and have the following variable `X_train`:

```
import scipy .io
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DIRECTORY + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
```

The shape of `X_train` is (124800, 784).

Now, I want to reshape this dataset so that it becomes a 3D tensor of the shape (124800, 28, 28).

I can reshape one instance of the data as follows:

```
X_train[index].reshape((28,28))
```

However, the following loop does not work:

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
    X_train[i] = X_train[i].reshape((28,28))
```

What can I do to reshape my dataset so it gets the shape (124800, 28, 28)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the whole array like this:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,28,28), order='F')
```

Matlab uses column-major order (see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html)), so you need to specify the order as `order='F'` in order to get the correct orientation. See the following example for the first letter (`w`):
[image]

Comment: Why would you advise using -1 instead of the actual number?

Comment: @amzon-ex: just for convenience and clarity: each 784 1D array gets reshaped into a 28x28 2D array, no matter how many of them there are. Of course you could also use (124800,28,28) for the same result.

Comment: I get it, so we only work with the reshaping and let numpy handle the rest; good idea. Great answer!